# Read all csv files in a zip with respective csv filenames as dataframe variable names

Tags: python, pandas, csv, zip

I need to read all CSV files from a zip folder in such a way that each file is read into a separate dataframe, and the dataframe name is the same as the name of the CSV file. Below is what I have done so far, I am having difficulty with assigning the file reading to the filename. Any help is much appreciated!

```
import os
import zipfile

csvNameList = []
with zipfile.ZipFile('../data/999915.zip') as z:
    for filename in z.namelist():
        csvNameList.append(filename.split(".")[1])
        df_name = filename.split(".")[1]
        df_name = pd.read_csv(z.open(filename),
                              header=None, 
                              sep='\|\|@@##', 
                              na_values='\\N')
```

I want to be able to reference the CSVs as data frames of the names stored within the csvNameList variable.

Comment: You probably want a `dict`, `d`, to store these, where the keys are `filename.split(".")[1]` and the values are `df` resulting from the `pd.read_csv` calls, allowing you to access the DataFrames with `d['your_filename']`

Comment: I think I almost had it, thanks for suggesting the dictionary approach, it worked for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will create a dictionary of dataframes:

```
with zipfile.ZipFile('../data/999915.zip') as z:
    dataframes = {filename.split(".")[1]: pd.read_csv(z.open(filename),header=None,sep='\|\|@@##',na_values='\\N') for filename in z.namelist()}
```

Comment: Hey thanks, the dictionary approach worked. I just had to add the "encoding= 'utf8' " argument to the value side of the dictionary, which I did not need otherwise if I were to load individual files from the zip.